# Unable to install redux and datepicker using npm

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

Tried using the following npm command to install `redux`, `react-datepicker`, and `react-router-dom`.

```
npm i react-redux @reduxjs/toolkit  react-datepicker react-router-dom@6
```

I noticed package.json isn't getting updated and the following is outputted in the terminal:

```
up to date, audited 157 packages in 16s

22 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

15 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I tried `npm set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/` after checking Stackoverflow.

How to solve this?

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Expecting
`react-datepicker`, `react-redux`, and the others to be added here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages ***were*** installed, the vulnerability warnings are ***just*** warnings though, and can generally be ignored. Run `npm audit fix` if you want to update/fix them.

Make sure you are in the correct directory for installing project dependencies, e.g. the project's root directory, then try running the following:

```
npm i -S react-redux @reduxjs/toolkit react-datepicker react-router-dom@6
```

This should install ***and*** update the package.json file. The `-S` or `--save` flag does this in older Node and NPM versions.

Comment: I tried the save flag before and now after running your suggested command I am getting up to date,
``audited 157 packages in 21s

22 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details``
so the packages are updated, but it's not showing up in the package.json file is that not necassary?(Never tried otherwise).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SakshamJain Check that you are in the correct directory, you should be in the project's root directory.

Comment: Heyy, thanks a lot its working I wasn't saving the project so it appeared when I tried to save my file that dependencies where added. Thank you.